# Improve file extension detection and restriction on upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know there are many questions and answers related to this but I would like to know the best way to do the restriction on file extension on both server and client side.

**PHP**

```
$allowedTypes = array('gif', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'rar', 'zip', 'txt');

$File_Name          = strtolower($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
$File_Ext           = pathinfo($File_Name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($File_Ext, $allowedTypes)) {
    die('Unsupported File format!');
}
```

**JS**

```
var ftype = $('#uploadfile')[0].files[0].type; // get file type

        //allowed file types
        switch(ftype)
        {
            case 'image/png':
            case 'image/gif':
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
            case 'text/plain':
            case 'text/html':
            case 'application/x-zip-compressed':
            case 'application/x-rar-compressed':
            case 'application/octet-stream':
            case 'application/pdf':
            case 'application/msword':
            case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
            case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
            case 'video/mp4':
                break;
            default:
                notify("Unsupported file type!");
                return false
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute at `<input type="file">` element

> **accept**
>
> If the value of the `type` attribute is file, this attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts;
>   otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of
>   unique content type specifiers:
>
> - A file extension starting with the STOP character (U+002E). (E.g.:    ".jpg,.png,.doc")

```html
<input type="file" accept=".gif,.png,.jpeg,.jpg,.pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.mp3,.mp4,.rar,.zip,.txt" />
```

Comment: ok. But wont it be an easy modification by any malicious user?

Comment: @Ayan _"But wont it be an easy modification by any malicious user?"_ Not certain what you mean?

Comment: Well, with my limited knowledge I think any user can change the accept attribute to accept any type of file from the console. Plus I am in need of showing users an alert that the chosen file is not supported.

Comment: @Ayan The `Open File` dialog will not display file types which are not listed at `accept` attribute. Yes, user can change `html`, `javascript` at document, though not `php`.